# Push Array no me funciona al hacer una llamada con axios

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Tengo el siguiente código JS, para llenar un array

```
<script>
export default {
    data() {

        return{

        varIngreso:null,
        charIngreso:null,
        ingresos:[],
        varTotalIngreso:[],
        varMesIngreso:[]
        }
    },
    methods:{
        getIngreso(){
            axios.get("api/escritorio").then(({ data })=>(this.ingresos = data));


            this.ingresos.map(function(x){
                this.varTotalIngreso.push(x.total);
                this.varMesIngreso.push(x.mes);

            });
```

El problema es que el array ingresos si me lo llena de datos, pero al momento de hacer el push a las otras 2 variables array con la función `map()` simplemente me los deja vacíos , ¿Algún consejo?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hay dos errores comunes aquí.

1. La llamada `axios` es asíncrono, por lo tanto el `map` de su variable `ingresos` podría ejecutarse antes o después de que la llamada tenga éxito, esto es impredecible, la solución más próxima es añadir este método en el `then`
2. El contexto de `this` no es el correcto si quiere hacer referencia al componente dentro de una función anónima, podría tener dos soluciones, crear una variable temporal `let vm = this` antes del map, o seguir utilizando las arrow functions.

Solución 1

```
   axios.get("api/escritorio").then((data)=>{
        this.ingresos = data;
        let vm = this;
        this.ingresos.map(function(x){
            vm.varTotalIngreso.push(x.total);
             vm.varMesIngreso.push(x.mes);
        });
    });
```

Solución 2

```
  axios.get("api/escritorio").then((data)=>{
        this.ingresos = data;
        this.ingresos.map((x)=>{
            this.varTotalIngreso.push(x.total);
            this.varMesIngreso.push(x.mes);
        });
    });
```